# Force Flask to Wait for Form Submission Event Before Function Execution

Tags: python, flask

I am building my first Flask app and have the following app with a route:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request 
from dbConnect import get_config_tables
import pandas  

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/config', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def config_reader():
    ID = request.form.get("ID")
    inputID = 12036
    result = get_config_tables(inputID)
    df = result.head(10)
    return render_template('config.html',  inputID = ID, tables=[df.to_html(classes='data', header = "true")])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The function `get_config_tables` is a python function I wrote that communicates with a SQL Server and grabs some tables. When I hard code the `inputID` into `get_config_tables` the function runs as expected inside the Flask app and the HTML is printed to screen as expected.

However, when I instead try and pass the value `ID` as `get_config_tables(ID)` then I get errors. I *think* Flask is trying to execute my function before an ID value is passed, but since that function requires an input value, it will fail until a valid one is entered.

Is there a way I can force Flask to wait to execute the function `get_config_tables` until the submit event button is clicked?

If any further information is needed to better understand my problem I am happy to provide it.

The corresponding HTML is:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

<h6>

Get a config table
<br><br>

<form action = "{{url_for('config_reader')}}" method = "POST">
    <input type = "text" name = "ID" placeholder = "Enter a confid ID">
    <button> Submit </button>

You entered {{inputID}}.

<hline>
<br><br>
The results are:
<br>
</h6> 
<small>
<center>
{% for table in tables %}
            {{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
</center>
</small>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: it's not trying to execute before the id is passed. You sure you have the id in your request? Did you double check and print its value? Also what is the error message you get?

Comment: @TheFool, yes, the HTML includes `You entered {{inputID}}` and when a value is entered it prints to screen after I hit submit. So I know something is being passed.

Comment: not the html, your backend. You are trying to access the id there. Also show the error thats most important, anything else doesn't matter all that much.

Comment: also show your function thats is taking the id as argument.

Comment: This seems to be the most relevant error I get. ```pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select * from table where ConfigID = None': ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'None'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")```

Comment: This part `ConfigID = None` indicates to me a value of `None` is being passed to my function from the form.

Comment: When I hard code the value, that portion is `ConfigID = 12345`

Comment: ok now, update your question and add the error message. also put a print(id) right before you call the function. And again add the function itself.

Comment: before the form was submitted, how do you even show the page? if its using that function that needs an id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are using this page even when there is no ID since you have the form on the same page as the tables.

This means not every time your endpoint is hit, an ID is sent with the request, you see you also have a GET method registered. Typically, the ID would not be in that request.

So you need to check if this id is indeed there and only then try to send your table data.

So the most naive way I can come up with is to use an if statement to check whether the id exists.

```
@app.route('/config', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def config_reader():
    ID = request.form.get("ID")

    t = get_config_tables(ID).head(10).to_html(
        classes='data', header = "true"
    ) if ID else '<table></table>'

    return render_template('config.html',  inputID = ID, tables= [t])
```

I haven't tested this but this is the gist of how to check for the id.